# on clicking the particular number in the table, how do i make it redirect to different popups/table

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
//http request from json data
$http({
     method: 'GET',
     url: '/Home/GetJson'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
     console.log(response);
     $scope.jsonData = response;

     var data = response.data;
     $scope.ngData = response.data;
})
```

table created from json data is as below:

```
    var table = $('<table id="Table"></table>');
    var someRow = "<tr class='someClass' ><th id='header1' >Product</th><th>P1</th><th>P2</th><th>P3</th><th>P4</th><th>Total</th></tr>"; 
    $("#Table").append(someRow);
    for (var i = 0; i <data.length; i++) {
        var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
        for (var key in data[i]) {
            var td = $('<td></td>');
            td.attr('class', key);
            td.append("<a href='#'>" + data[i][key] + "</a>");
            tr.append(td);
        }
        table.append(tr);
    }
    $('#div1').html(table.prepend(someRow));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is not related to AngularJS.
it s a pure JS/JQuery code.

Therefore; I'll provide a reply on JQuery.

You need to create dynamicly; AFTER the cell is created; for every button an event to load the popup such as :

```
for(var i=0;i< data.length;i++)
{
  for(var key=0;j< data[i].length;j++)
  {
    data[i][j].addEventListener('click',function(){
      // Your On Click code to load your modal

    },false);
  }
}
```

This code shall be added AFTER the element are on your DOM; therefore after : `$('#div1').html(table.prepend(someRow));`

------ EDIT

**After more analysis; I see that you mixed AngularJS and JQUERY ! 
This is a very huge mistake as JS and Angular does not work the same.**

Therefore; OR you change the loading part of your Json; and add a plan $ajax loading system; OR you remove your dynamic creating of DOM with Jquery and add a standard Angular JS behaviour